# How do you make a platform that needs all players to tp to a sub room?

Tags: rec-room

I'm trying to make a quest and need to makes something that's like in golden trophy where all players have to stand on a platform to move on. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you could you use a trigger volume tracking players and (with the green pin) checking the number of players in the volume and comparing that to the total number of players (using the Team Mapping chip).

Comment: He is asking for the total number of players, so he should use the player event chip instead of the team mapper chip to get that.